# Limitar la ejecución de una función recursiva a una sola ejecución

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ecmascript-6

Tengo un programa en el cuál quiero ejecutar una función que vacía una cola de trabajo respetando el orden de modo que, recursivamente, va procesando y eliminando el primer elemento. Veamos un ejemplo:

```
function process_queue() {
    if(queue.size > 0){
        process(queue.head())
            .done( function() { // Si se ha procesado bien, elimina y sigue
                queue.delete_first();
                process_queue();
            }
    }
}
```

El asunto es que, como el procesado puede fallar, es necesario un bucle que reintente constantemente el procesado, por ejemplo:

```
setInterval(function() {
    process_queue()
}, 15000);
```

Sin embargo, no quiero tener múltiples ejecuciones realizando el process_queue al mismo tiempo, porque por concurrencia tal vez procesan el mismo elemento más de una vez.

Esto en otros lenguajes lo puedes solucionar con un lock. Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo se puede limitar tal ejecución en JavaScript?

Comment: De pronto este link te pueda ayudar:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346694/how-to-implement-a-lock-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346694/how-to-implement-a-lock-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en Javascript puedes lograr asincronía, pero si no utilizas web workers (como en tu caso) los problemas de concurrencia que temes no van a darse. No hay necesidad de implementar control de la concurrencia alguno en tu código.

Te recomiendo que leas el siguiente artículo

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

En especial la sección "Never blocking":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Never_blocking

Answer (score 0):

Yo declararía una variable antes de la función seteándola en `true` cuando se procese bien.

Algo así:

```
var lock = false;
function process_queue() {
  if(lock){
      if(queue.size > 0){
        process(queue.head())
        .done( function() { // Si se ha procesado bien, elimina y sigue
           lock = true;
           queue.delete_first();
           process_queue();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva, buen día!